# CoreImage: CIImage write JPG is shifting colors [macOS]

Tags: swift, macos, colors, jpeg, core-image

Using CoreImage to filter photos, I have found that saving to JPG file will result in an image that has a subtle but visible blue hue. In this example using a B&W image, the histogram reveals how the colors have been shifted in the saved file.

*---Input* [image: Input Histogram]

*Output* [[image: Output Histogram]] Histogram shows the color layers are offset

**-- Issue demonstrated with MacOS 'Preview' App**

I can show a similar result using only the Preview App.

1. test image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3f03.jpg
2. Open the JPG image using Preview.
3. Export to JPEG at any 'Quality' other than the default (85%?)
4. Open the exported file and look at the Histogram, and the same color shifting can be seen as I experience within my app.

[image]

**-- Issue demonstrated in custom MacOS App**

The code here is as bare bones as possible, creating a CIImage from the photo and immediately saving it without performing any filters. In this example I chose 0.61 for compression as it resulted in a similar file size as the original. The distortion seems to be broader if using a higher compression ratio, but I could not find any value that would eliminate it.

```
if let img = CIImage(contentsOf: url) {
   let dest = procFolder.url(named: "InOut.jpg")
   img.jpgWrite(url: dest)
}

extension CIImage {
    func jpgWrite(url: URL) {

        let prop: [NSBitmapImageRep.PropertyKey: Any] = [
            .compressionFactor: 0.61
        ]

        let bitmap = NSBitmapImageRep(ciImage: self)
        let data = bitmap.representation(using: NSBitmapImageRep.FileType.jpeg, properties: prop)

        do {
            try data?.write(to: url, options: .atomic)
        } catch {
            log.error(error)
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 1: Using @Frank Schlegel's answer for saving JPG file**

The JPG now carries a Color Sync Profile, and I can (unscientifically) track a ~10% performance boost for portrait images (less for landscape), which are nice improvements. But, unfortunately the resulting file is still skewing the colors in the same way demonstrated in the histograms above.

```
extension CIImage {
   static let writeContext = CIContext(mtlDevice: MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!, options: [
        // using an extended working color space allows you to retain wide gamut information, e.g., if the input is in DisplayP3
        .workingColorSpace: CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.extendedSRGB)!,
        .workingFormat: CIFormat.RGBAh // 16 bit color depth, needed in extended space
    ])

    func jpgWrite(url: URL) {
       // write the output in the same color space as the input; fallback to sRGB if it can't be determined
        let outputColorSpace = colorSpace ?? CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)!
        do {
            try CIImage.writeContext.writeJPEGRepresentation(of: self, to: url, colorSpace: outputColorSpace, options: [:])
        } catch {
        }
    }
}
```

**Question:**

How can I open a B&W JPG as a CIImage, and re-save a JPG file avoiding any color shifting?

Comment: they have different ColorSync profiles

Comment: @LeoDabus I had noticed that, and tried setting colorSyncProfileData: NSBitmapImageRep.PropertyKey, but wasn't sure how to have it match the ColorSync profile of the source file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found the underlying cause of this issue and therefore no 'true' solution as I was seeking. In discussion with @Frank Schlegel, it led to a belief that it is an artifact of Apple's jpeg converter. And the issue was certainly more apparent when using test files that appear monochrome but actually had small amount of color info in them.

The simplest fix for my app was to ensure there was no color in the source image, so I drop the saturation to 0 prior to saving the file.

```
    let params = [
        "inputBrightness": brightness,  // -1...1, This filter calculates brightness by adding a bias value: color.rgb + vec3(brightness)
        "inputContrast": contrast,      // 0...2, this filter uses the following formula: (color.rgb - vec3(0.5)) * contrast + vec3(0.5)
        "inputSaturation": saturation   // 0...2
    ]
    image.applyingFilter("CIColorControls", parameters: params)
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a color sync issue (as Leo pointed out) – more specifically a mismatch/misinterpretation of color spaces between input, processing, and output.

When you are calling `NSBitmapImageRep(ciImage:)`, there's actually a lot happening under the hood. The system actually needs to *render* the `CIImage` you are providing to get the bitmap data of the result. It does so by creating a `CIContext` with default (device-specific) settings, using it to process your image (with all filters and transformations applied to it), and then giving you the raw bitmap data of the result. In the process, there are multiple color space conversions happening that you can't control when using this API (and seemingly don't lead to the result you intended). I don't like these "convenience" APIs for rendering `CIImage`s for this reason and I see a lot of questions on SO that are related to them.

I recommend you instead use a `CIContext` to render your `CIImage` into a JPEG file. This gives you direct control over color spaces and more:

```
let input = CIImage(contentsOf: url)

// ideally you create this context once and re-use it because it's an expensive object
let context = CIContext(mtlDevice: MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!, options: [
    // using an extended working color space allows you to retain wide gamut information, e.g., if the input is in DisplayP3
    .workingColorSpace: CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.extendedSRGB)!,
    .workingFormat: CIFormat.RGBAh // 16 bit color depth, needed in extended space
])

// write the output in the same color space as the input; fallback to sRGB if it can't be determined
let outputColorSpace = input.colorSpace ?? CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)!

context.writeJPEGRepresentation(of: input, to: dest, colorSpace: outputColorSpace, options: [kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality: 0.61])
```

Please let me know if you still see a discrepancy when using this API.

Comment: I incorporated your answer and I can see a performance improvement, but unfortunately it did not fix the problem. I updated the question to include your recommendation.

Comment: This is most interesting. It seems to be an issue in Apple's JPEG implementation. When exporting the same image with Affinity Photo I don't see this kind of "histogram bleeding". From how the colors are shifted I assume Apple uses some kind of perception-based model to do the compression in, but I don't know enough of how JPEG works to deduce more... Are you working with grayscale images only? Then you could try to work in a grayscale color space.

Comment: I need to handle color and grayscale. Another finding today: If I apply CIColorControls filter with inputSaturation = 0 just prior to saving, the resulting file looks correct. So, does that indicate that the color artifact is occurring in context.writeJPEGRepresentation() when the context is rendering the CIImage and prior to writing the JPEG file?

Comment: This sounds like colo sync is converting the image wrongly when "importing" it into the context... very strange. Could you please try to use different working color spaces (`.sRGB` and `.linearSRGB`) for me?

Comment: I tried several combinations of color spaces in both the CIContext initialization, and the specified outputColorSpace used by writeJPEGRepresentation(). No difference in output.

Comment: I am switching gears to now come up with the best workaround.  I am using CIAreaAverage to determine if the input image is grayscale (looking for a minimal differential between the r,g,b values), and then, if so, I use CIColorControls to squash the Saturation to 0.  Do you think this is a reasonable approach? Can you think of a more efficient way?

Comment: Hmm, `CIAreaAverage` is a rather expensive filter, so this solution is obviously not ideal. I was wondering... does the same happen when you export as PNG or TIFF?

Comment: writeContext.writePNGRepresentation(of: self, to: url, format: CIFormat.RGBAh, colorSpace: outputColorSpace, options: [:]) appears to be accurate. Is there a way to leverage that?

Comment: Then it seems Apple's JPEG conversion is at fault here. Maybe you can try to use Core Graphics to create a JPEG image and see if it has the same issues.